# odoo: Internal Server Error, where is the bug?

Tags: odoo, internal-server-error

I'm running odoo server on windows, I am getting the famous "500 Inernal server error" but i don't now the source of the bug!

Even if I stop/restart the server I still get the error.

I looked for a log file  and I found "openerp-server.txt".

this is the end of the log file:

```
2016-04-08 18:17:31,045 4816 ERROR developpement werkzeug: Error on request: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
       File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 165, in execute
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\service\server.py", line 290, in app
    return self.app(e, s)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\service\wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\service\wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\http.py", line 1292, in
__call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\http.py", line 1266, in
__call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)   File "werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\http.py", line 1444, in dispatch
    response = self.get_response(httprequest, result, explicit_session)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\http.py", line 1375, in get_response
    result = request.registry['ir.http']._handle_exception(e)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\website\models\ir_http.py", line 196, in _handle_exception
    return super(ir_http, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_http.py", line 145, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\http.py", line 668, in
_handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\http.py", line 1372, in get_response
    result.flatten()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\http.py", line 1243, in flatten
    self.response.append(self.render())   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\http.py", line 1237, in render
    context=request.context)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\website\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 173, in render
    return super(view, self).render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, values=values, engine=engine, context=context)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_ui_view.py", line 1022, in render
    return self.pool[engine].render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, qcontext, loader=loader, context=context)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 263, in render
    return self.render_node(self.get_template(id_or_xml_id, qwebcontext), qwebcontext)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 302, in render_node
    result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 323, in render_element
    g_inner.append(self.render_node(current_node, qwebcontext))   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 300, in render_node
    result = self._render_tag[t_render](self, element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 447, in render_tag_call
    return self.render(cr, uid, template, d)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 263, in render
    return self.render_node(self.get_template(id_or_xml_id, qwebcontext), qwebcontext)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 302, in render_node
    result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 323, in render_element
    g_inner.append(self.render_node(current_node, qwebcontext))   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 300, in render_node
    result = self._render_tag[t_render](self, element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 447, in render_tag_call
    return self.render(cr, uid, template, d)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 263, in render
    return self.render_node(self.get_template(id_or_xml_id, qwebcontext), qwebcontext)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 302, in render_node
    result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 323, in render_element
    g_inner.append(self.render_node(current_node, qwebcontext))   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 284, in render_node
    self, element, attribute_name, attribute_value, qwebcontext)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 359, in render_att_att
    return [(attribute_name[6:], self.eval(attribute_value, qwebcontext))]   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 207, in eval
    raise_qweb_exception(message="Could not evaluate expression %r" % expr, expression=expr, template=template)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 204, in eval
    return qwebcontext.safe_eval(expr)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160406\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb.py", line 89, in safe_eval
    return eval(expr, None, locals_dict, nocopy=True, locals_builtins=True)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
8.0-20160406\server\openerp\tools\safe_eval.py", line 314, in safe_eval
    return eval(c, globals_dict, locals_dict)   File "", line 1, in <module>
     QWebException: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'" while evaluating 'res_company.name'
```

where is the bug?

Comment: Any custom modules installed? Had it running before without an error?

Comment: @programme  yes i was working on a module

Comment: Does your module depend on other already existing models? if yes try adding the modules need for them in your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a typo in a model name passed to `self.pool.get(model_name)` which in turns returns `None` and you get a late failure. Replace `self.pool.get(model_name)` in your code with `self.pool[model_name]` to get a crash where the bug is.